# Flow-type check for styles in JSX

Tags: reactjs, sass, flowtype

I am trying to improve the flow-type coverage in my react project. Currently, I don't have any coverage modules added in the project and using Atom with Nuclide for coverage check. I keep getting the "Not covered by Flow" warning on each className when importing styles like below:

```
import styles from './styles.scss';
```

[image]

This is reducing the flow coverage. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to .flowconfig these lines:

```
[options]
module.name_mapper='.*\.scss$' -> 'empty/object'
```

What it does is it will make Flow think that your styles is a JS empty object and just skip it. Or better, declare a libdefs and map the .scss to them.

EDIT:
Sometimes I just don't understand Flow at all, here, this is another way to do it, but it isn't elegant:

```
// scss.js 
// @flow

const styles: {[string]: string} = {};

export default styles;

_____________________________________________________________________

// .flowconfig
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension='scss' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/path/to/scss.js'
module.file_ext=.scss
```

Comment: I am not getting "required module not found" error in flowtype. The issue is in flow coverage.

Comment: Still getting the same coverage warning.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the 'scss.js' inside of 'flow-typed' folder?

Comment: Yeah, the `scss.js` file is inside `flow-typed/npm` directory.

Comment: Tried putting it inside `flow-typed` also. Same result.

Comment: Umh, just one more try! Did you add "// @flow" on top of "scss.js"?

Comment: Same warning. Tried scss.js file is inside `flow-typed/npm`  and `flow-typed` directories after adding `// @flow`.

Comment: @AbhijithSJ Please try with this way, this is the guaranteed way but it's not very pretty.